# What are these extra bytes coming from the iPhone camera in portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, ios8, avfoundation, avcapturesession

When I get a frame from `- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection` I am getting back the following data:

- BytesPerRow: 1,472  Length: 706,560  Height: 480  Width: 360  format:
  BGRA

This is from the front camera on an iPhone 6 plus.
This doesn't make sense because bytes per row should be (width * channels) (channels in this case is 4). However, it's (width+8)*channels. Where is this extra 8 bytes coming from?

Here's my code:
Attaching the output to the session I set the orientation to portrait

```
bool attachOutputToSession(AVCaptureSession *session, id cameraDelegate)
{
    assert(cameraDelegate);

    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *m_videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

    //create a queue for capturing frames
    dispatch_queue_t captureQueue  = dispatch_queue_create("captureQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    //Use the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate capabilities of CameraDelegate:
    [m_videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:cameraDelegate queue:captureQueue];

    //setup the video outputs
    m_videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;

    NSNumber *framePixelFormat = [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];//This crashes with 24RGB b/c that isn't supported on iPhone
    m_videoOutput.videoSettings = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:framePixelFormat forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];

    //Check if it already has an output from a previous session
    if ([session canAddOutput:m_videoOutput])
    {
        [session addOutput:m_videoOutput];
    }

    //set connection settings
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in m_videoOutput.connections)
    {
        if (connection.isVideoMirroringSupported)
            connection.videoMirrored = true;
        if (connection.isVideoOrientationSupported)
            connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait; 
    }

    return true;
}
```

When I set the orientation to LandscapeRight I do not have this issue. The bytes per row is equal to width*channels.

Here's where I'm getting the numbers mentioned above:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK turns out this is part of the image "stride". If an image width is not divisible by the chosen memory allotment then this extra padding is included. When I receive the portrait image it is 360x480. Since 360 is not divisible by 16, 8 extra bytes are added as padding. 16 is the memory space in this case. 
I was not having this issue before because 480 is divisible by 16. 
You can get this number by calling `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane (imageBuffer, 1);`
What's weird though, is that it returns a 0 the first time, 1 the second time, and so on until it reaches the real buffer level (8). Then it returns 0 again on the ninth image.

According to rpappalax on this page http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/iOS-capture-problem-td4656685.html

> The stride is effectively CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane() and
>   includes padding (if any).  When no padding is present
>   CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane() will be equal to
>   CVPixelBufferGetWidth(), otherwise it'll be greater.

Although that wasn't exactly my experience.

Comment: 32BRGA is a single planar format, so there is no reason to mess with CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane.  Just use CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow to get the stride.

Comment: You're right, this works just fine. However, I was dealing with an image structure that only took the bytes, width, height, and total size. So it was important for me to figure out how to calculate this only off the data I had later.